# Reducir número de un campo INT al realizar un préstamo MYSQL

Tags: php, mysql

Tengo dos tablas, una tabla **préstamo** y una tabla **posts**, que están relacionadas por el `id` de la tabla **posts**. Pensaba que al tener los dos, los campos cantidad, este se reduciría en la tabla posts cada vez que seleccionaba una cantidad en la tabla préstamos.

Añado el formulario para añadir un nuevo préstamo:

```
<div class="body">
    <h2>Añadir Préstamo</h2>
    <br>
    <?php 
        if(isset($_SESSION['ana']))
        {
            echo $_SESSION['ana'];
            unset($_SESSION['ana']);
        }
    ?>
    <form method="post" action="">
        
        
        <div class="input-group">
            <span class="input-label">id_libro</span>
            <select class="half" name="id_libro">
                <?php 
                    $tbl_name = 'tbl_posts';
                    $query = $obj->select_data($tbl_name);
                    $res = $obj->execute_query($conn,$query);
                    if($res==true)
                    {
                        $count_rows = $obj->num_rows($res);
                        if($count_rows>0)
                        {
                            while ($row=$obj->fetch_data($res)) {
                                $cat_id=$row['id'];
                                $title=$row['titu_'.$_SESSION['lang']];
                                ?>
                                <option value="<?php echo $cat_id; ?>"><?php echo $cat_id; ?>-<?php echo $title; ?></option>
                                <?php
                            }
                        }
                        else{
                            ?>
                            <option value="0">None</option>
                            <?php 
                        }
                    }
                ?>
            </select>
        </div>
        <div class="input-group">
            <span class="input-label">id_usuario</span>
            <select class="half" name="id_usuario">
                <?php 
                    $tbl_name = 'tbl_usuarios';
                    $query = $obj->select_data($tbl_name);
                    $res = $obj->execute_query($conn,$query);
                    if($res==true)
                    {
                        $count_rows = $obj->num_rows($res);
                        if($count_rows>0)
                        {
                            while ($row=$obj->fetch_data($res)) {
                                $usu=$row['id'];
                                $nom=$row['nom_com'];
                                ?>
                                <option value="<?php echo $usu; ?>"><?php echo $usu; ?>-<?php echo $nom; ?></option>
                                <?php
                            }
                        }
                        else{
                            ?>
                            <option value="0">None</option>
                            <?php 
                        }
                    }
                ?>
            </select>
        </div>

        <div class="input-group">
            <span class="input-label">Fecha Prestamo</span>
            <input type="date" name="fecha_prestamo" id="fecha_prestamo" class="form-control" required>
        </div>
        <div class="input-group">
            <span class="input-label">Fecha Devolucion</span>
            <input type="date" name="fecha_devolucion" id="fecha_devolucion" class="form-control"  required>
        </div>
        <div class="input-group">
            <span class="input-label">Cantidad</span>
            <input class="half" type="number" name="cantidad" value="<?php echo $cantidad; ?>"</input>
        </div>
        <div class="input-group">
            <span class="input-label">Estado</span>
            <input class="half" type="number"  min="0" max="1" name="estado" value="<?php echo $estado; ?>"</input>
        </div>
        <div class="input-group">
            <input class="btn-primary btn-sm" type="submit" name="submit" value="<?php echo $lang['add_post'] ?>">
            <button type="button" class="btn-primary btn-sm" onclick="history.back()">Atrás</button>
        </div>
    </form>

    <?php 
        if(isset($_POST['submit']))
        {
            
            $id_libro = $obj->sanitize($conn,$_POST['id_libro']);
            $id_usuario = $obj->sanitize($conn,$_POST['id_usuario']);
            $fecha_prestamo = $obj->sanitize($conn,$_POST['fecha_prestamo']);
            $fecha_devolucion = $obj->sanitize($conn,$_POST['fecha_devolucion']);
            $cantidad = $obj->sanitize($conn,$_POST['cantidad']);
            $estado = $obj->sanitize($conn,$_POST['estado']);
            

            $data="
            
                id_libro='$id_libro',
                id_usuario='$id_usuario',
                fecha_prestamo='$fecha_prestamo',
                fecha_devolucion='$fecha_devolucion',
                cantidad='$cantidad',
                estado='$estado'
                
            ";

            $tbl_name = 'tbl_prestamo';
            $query = $obj->insert_data($tbl_name,$data);
            $res = $obj->execute_query($conn,$query);

            if($res == true)
            {
                $_SESSION['ana'] = "<div class='success'>".$lang['aña_bien']."</div>";
                header('location:'.SITEURL.'admin/index.php?page=presta');
            }
            else
            {
                $_SESSION['ana'] = "<div class='error'>".$lang['aña_mal']."</div>";
                header('location:'.SITEURL.'admin/index.php?page=add_prestamop');
            }
        }
    ?>
</div>
```

EDITO:
He añadido las siguientes líneas a la última parte del código:

```
if($res == true )
            {   $tbl_name = 'tbl_prestamo';
                $tbl_posts = 'tbl_posts'; 
                $query ="UPDATE $tbl_posts,$tbl_name SET $tbl_posts.cantidad = $tbl_posts.cantidad-$tbl_name.cantidad  where $tbl_posts.id = $id_libro";
                $consulta = $obj->execute_query($conn,$query);  
                if($consulta == true){
                $_SESSION['ana'] = "<div class='success'>".$lang['aña_bien']."</div>";
                header('location:'.SITEURL.'admin/index.php?page=presta');
                }
            }
```

El problemas es que solo resta uno , da igual la cantidad que le pongas.
Añado mas código para poder responder a DjCrazy, no sabía que tengo que añadir tantas funciones para solo restar o sumar, antes me han dicho con un `trigger` pero no se si se puede llamar a uno mediante `php`.

Y he borrado la otra parte de la pregunta porque ya lo he solucionado.

Comment: Entonces cual es tu pregunta? Dices tener 2 tablas `prestamos` y `libros`, pero no hay esta ultima

Comment: la tabla posts es la tabla libros.

Comment: Quizás has modificado las relaciones de las tablas ejecuta esta consulta y fijate si coinciden los resultados `select * from tbl_prestamo pres 
inner join tbl_posts libro on pres.id_libro = libro.id; `

Comment: Si que coinciden entre si : https://ibb.co/cJTPjJh

Comment: ¿Cuál es la consulta que no funciona?

Comment: Lo que quiero hacer , es que si yo tengo en el campo cantidad de posts el valor 10, que este se reduzca a medida que hago préstamos , si hago un préstamo de un libro  que en la tabla posts cantidad es 10 y yo selecciono la cantidad al hacer el prestamo y por ejemplo pongo 5 , que el valor del campo cantidad de posts se reduzca.

Comment: No entiendo mucho cuál es el problema. Además, esto deberías resolverlo desde un TRIGGER. Cuando se haga un préstamo de un libro, lanzas el TRIGGER para que reste 1 a la tabla de libros disponibles; igualmente, cuando el libro sea devuelto, deberías lanzar otro TRIGGER que añada 1 a la cantidad de libros disponibles,

Comment: ¿Pero con PHP se puede hacer ?

Answer (score 1):

Te propongo una solución con funciones anidadas, puede parecer compleja pero es efectiva. Trataré de explicar cada función...

- En la función **prestamoLibro()** haces el registro del libro prestado y si se inserta el registro de manera exitosa, se ejecuta la función **actualizarLibrosDisponibles()** a la cual le envías por parámetro el id del libro, la cantidad y la acción préstamo para hacer la resta de los libros prestados.
- La función **actualizarLibrosDisponibles()**, recibe los parámetros y a su vez ejecuta la función **cantidadLibros()** que te va a devolver la cantidad de libros disponibles para hacer la operación matemática.
- Luego, la función **actualizarLibrosDisponibles()**, realiza el cálculo de los libros existentes versus la cantidad que recibe por parámetro y ejecuta la actualización de la cantidad de libros.
- Por último, la función **devolverLibro()**, hace un proceso similar, solo que actualiza  la tabla de préstamo con la fecha de devolución del libro y actualiza la tabla de libros con la cantidad de libros devueltos.

**PD:** *Utilicé consultas preparadas para evitar ataques por inyección SQL*. Si deseas un ejemplo más simple, o aclaraciones en este ejemplo, comenta. Y no olvides adaptar el código del ejemplo a tu proyecto, es posible que hayan partes que no coincidan ya que este código es solo ilustrativo.

```
//Préstamo de libros
public function prestamoLibro() {
    $query = $conexion->prepare("INSERT INTO tbl_prestamo (id_libro, id_usuario, fecha_prestamo, fecha_devolucion, cantidad) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?);
    $query->bindParam(1, $_POST["id_libro"]);
    $query->bindParam(2, $_POST["id_usuario"]);
    $query->bindParam(3, $_POST["fecha_prestamo"]);
    $query->bindParam(4, NULL);
    $query->bindParam(5, $_POST["cantidad"]);
    
    if ($query->execute()) {
        //Si se hace el insert, ejecutas la función cantidad de libros enviándole los parámetros id_libro y cantidad
        actualizarLibrosDisponibles($_POST["id_libro"], $_POST["cantidad"], $accion = "prestamo");
    } else {
        return "error";
    }
    
    $query->close();
}

//Actualizar la cantidad de libros
public function actualizarLibrosDisponibles($id_libro, $cantidad, $accion) {
    //Consultas la cantidad de libros disponibles actualmente para hacer la operación matemática correspondiente
    $cantidadActual = cantidadLibros($id_libro);

    //Si la acción recibida en los parámetros es préstamo, se resta la cantidad, en caso contrario, se suma
    if($accion == "prestamo") {
        //Restar la cantidad
        $nuevaCantidad = $cantidadActual['cantidad'] - $cantidad;
    } else if($accion == "devolucion") {
        //Sumar la cantidad
        $nuevaCantidad = $cantidadActual['cantidad'] + $cantidad;
    }

    //Ejecutar la actualización
    $query = $conexion->prepare("UPDATE tbl_post SET cantidad = ? WHERE id_libro = ?);
    $query->bindParam(1, $nuevaCantidad);
    $query->bindParam(5, $id_libro);
    
    if ($query->execute()) {
        return "success";
    } else {
        return "error";
    }
    
    $query->close();
}

//Consultar la cantidad de libros
public function cantidadLibros($id_libro){
    $query = $conexion->prepare("SELECT cantidad FROM tbl_post WHERE id = ?");
    $query -> bindParam(1, $id_libro);
    $query -> execute();
    return $query -> fetch();
    
    $query->close();
}

//Devolver libros
public function devolverLibro() {
    $query = $conexion->prepare("UPDATE tbl_prestamo SET fecha_devolucion = ? WHERE id = ?);
    $query->bindParam(1, $_POST["fecha_devolucion"]);
    $query->bindParam(5, $_POST["id_prestamo"]);
    
    if ($query->execute()) {
        //Si se hace el update, ejecutas la función cantidad de libros enviándole los parámetros id_libro y cantidad
        actualizarLibrosDisponibles($_POST["id_libro"], $_POST["cantidad"], $accion = "devolucion");
    } else {
        return "error";
    }
    
    $query->close();
}
```

Comment: he añadido el código que utilizo para el formulario,¿ tendría que cambiar la última parte del código para ejecutar las nuevas funciones?

Comment: En mi respuesta **te planteo una solución**, pero **no significa que deba ser de esa manera**, puede ser con un TRIGGER como dice A. Cedano... Puedes resolverlo tal y como tienes estructurado tu código, siguiendo una lógica similar a mi propuesta... en una misma acción 1- consultas la cantidad de libros actual de la tabla **posts** según el `id` del libro, 2- le restas la cantidad prestada, 3- actualizas la tabla **posts** con la nueva cantidad de libros disponibles y 4- insertas todo el registro del préstamo en la tabla **prestamos**. Mas tarde reviso si puedo actualizar mi respuesta.

Comment: Ok , esta noche lo intento resolver.

Comment: Pues al final no lo consigo

Comment: Actualizo la pregunta

Comment: Al menos ya lograste hacer que te reste algo, significa que vas por buen camino... Intenta consultar la cantidad de libros en `tbl_posts`, se lo asignas a una variable y haces la resta `$nuevaCantidad = $respuesta['cantidad'] - $_POST['cantidad']`, esto antes de hacer el `update` . Luego en el `update`, cambia  `$tbl_posts.cantidad = $tbl_posts.cantidad-$tbl_name.cantidad` por esto `$tbl_posts.cantidad = $nuevaCantidad`.

Comment: ¿como haría para almacenar el resultado del select en una variable?SELECT tbl_posts.cantidad FROM tbl_posts,tbl_prestamo where tbl_posts.id=tbl_prestamo.$id_libro

Comment: De manera similar a como lo haces en tu primer `select`... `$cat_id=$row['id'];`

Comment: `$prueba = "SELECT tbl_posts.cantidad FROM tbl_posts,tbl_prestamo where tbl_prestamo.id_libro='$id_libro' and tbl_posts.id=tbl_prestamo.id_libro";
    $probada = $obj->execute_query($conn,$prueba); 
    $ncantidad = $probada - $cantidad;
    $query ="UPDATE $tbl_posts,$tbl_name SET $tbl_posts.cantidad = $ncantidad  where $tbl_posts.id = '$id_libro'";
    $consulta = $obj->execute_query($conn,$query)`; Si lo dejo así siempre me resta mal ya que da igual la cantidad que tenga el campo tbl_posts.cantidad me da negativo el resultado.

Comment: Lo he solucionado al final paso el código por si ha alguien le vale y muchas gracias a @DjCrazy: `$prueba = "SELECT tbl_posts.cantidad FROM tbl_posts,tbl_prestamo where tbl_prestamo.id_libro='$id_libro' and tbl_posts.id=tbl_prestamo.id_libro";
    $probada = $obj->execute_query($conn,$prueba);
    $resultado = mysqli_fetch_row($probada);
    $ncantidad = $resultado[0] - $cantidad;`